# how can i check if vhost is enabled on tomcat7

Tags: tomcat7

I am trying to add a vhost to my already running tomcat7 server.

I already have my default application running on tomcat successfully.

```
<Host name="mydefault.com" appBase="webapps"
unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

<Host name="myNewHostDomain.com" 
appBase="wings_microx_cash_reports" 
unpackWars="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

i have added the domain as well on dns (godaddy) and ping is running fine.

But when i check the logs in /usr/share/tomcat7/logs, i do not see anyinfo with respect to my new vhost

Also, when i send in a http request to my new host, i see the default host app is running

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="mydefault.com">
```

Any pointers how i can check/rectify this?

Comment: found my mistake

i had not closed the host tag properly.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for false alarm

i had not closed the  tag pproperly.